# a matrix related question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A=\left(\matrix{a&b&0&0 \\ 0&a&b&0 \\ 0&0&a&b \\ 0&0&0&a  }\right) $

$ \boxed{1} $ Decompose $ A $ under the form $ aI + bJ $, where $I$ and $J$ are two matrices to be determined.

$\boxed{2}$ Prove that $\exists k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $J^k = 0.$

$\boxed{3}$ Deduce $A^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: You probably mean $aI + bJ$. Have you tried something?

Comment: It says "to be determined"...but it isn't really difficult to determine what the natural choices for $I,J$ are.

Comment: I downvoted. OP showed no effort or attempt.

Comment: Hints: for property 2, check [this page about nilpotent matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Characterization). You should be able to compute the characteristic polynomial very easily in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, observe that

$\begin{eqnarray*}
A & = & \left(\begin{array}{cccc}a & b & 0 & 0\\0 & a & b & 0\\0 & 0 & a & b\\0 & 0 & 0 & a\end{array}\right)\\
& = & \left(\begin{array}{cccc}a & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & a & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & a & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & a\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & b & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & b & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & b\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\\
& = & a\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)+b\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right),
\end{eqnarray*}$

so (as mentioned in the comments) there is a fairly natural choice for $I$ and $J$.

---

For the second part, the simplest thing to do in such situations is generally to multiply $J$ by itself a few times and see what happens. (In fact, looking ahead to part $3$, you'll need to know what the various powers of $J$ are, anyway, so this is pretty much all you *can* do.) You shouldn't have to do this very many times, so if you don't end up with the zero matrix fairly quickly, something has gone wrong.

---

For the third part, it is very useful to realize that for any $4\times 4$ matrix $B$, we have $IB=B=BI$. This means in particular that multiplication by $I$ is like leaving the matrix alone, and that $I$ commutes multiplicatively with any matrix. Usually, if $B,C$ are arbitrary same-sized square matrices, we have (for example) that $(B+C)^2=B^2+BC+CB+C^2\neq B^2+2BC+C^2$, since we won't generally have $BC=CB$. **However**, if we happen to know that $B$ and $C$ commute, then we don't have to worry about that sort of thing, and we **will** have $(B+C)^2=B^2+2BC+C^2$.

Further note that if $k$ is any non-negative integer, then $(aI)^k=a^kI^k$ and $(bJ)^k=b^kJ^k$. This is nice, because it means that $(bJ)^k=0$ for sufficiently large $k$ (refer to part $2$, and note that multiplying a $4\times 4$ matrix by the $4\times 4$ zero matrix will yield the zero matrix), and that $(aI)^k=a^kI$ for all $k$ (easy induction since $IB=B=BI$ for any $4\times 4$ matrix $B$)

Finally, since everything involved will commute, we may use the binomial expansion formula $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k y^kx^{n-k},$$ where $$\binom n k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$ In particular, we'll use this with $x=aI$ and $y=bJ$, so that the expression ends up being much nicer (as higher powers of $y=bJ$ will vanish).

---

Hopefully, that will be enough to get you going. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere, and I'll see about getting you unstuck.